# Selenium clicking from a mouse hover tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, click

I used

```
quotes = browser.find_element_by_id('CQ')
quotes.click()
```

But it returned

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"CQ"}
```

Maybe I'm wrong with my function/parameters.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to call `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` before your code

Comment: It may be useful to know where the code is being called from, since it looks like your selector is fine.

Comment: What is your exact _Manual Step_? _Mouse Hover_ or _click()_? Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DebanjanB Its hover, hover, then thirdly click.

Comment: So where are you exactly stuck? at which step?

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver Waits are sometimes necessary due to the nature of Page Loads. Try waiting until the Element is displayed/enabled first before clicking it. Python Selenium Docs for WebDriver Waits: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someid')))
```